# Wpf DataGrid adding new row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In Wpf DataGrid in the bottom there is an "blank new row" for adding new row. 
[image]

When I start adding new row (typing in "blank new row") the blank new row disappears
[image]
So in order to start adding new row I need Tab Of(lost focus) from current row.

How to make "empty new row" appear in the bottom when I'm adding new row?

Comment: This wouldn't make sense. I think the philosophy is that when the user starts adding a new row, they will fill out all of the necessary fields on that row before continuing to the next row. What are your design requirements here?

Comment: @MikeEason As soon as the new row enters edit mode another new row should appear. The use case is that when I am entering data in a new row, I want to be able to click off of the current "new row" into a new "new row". Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Set `CanUserAddRows` property of Datagrid to `True`